# Find discontinuities in an array of date in php

Tags: php

I have a sorted array of dates that looks like so :

```
$dates = Array('2014-10-01','2014-10-01','2014-10-02','2014-10-03','2014-10-05');
```

In this array we have two times (sometimes more, but it's normal in my script) the date Oct 1st but it's missing the 4th.

How can I detect that there is a discontinuity between the first value of the array, and the last value of the array (again, my array is sorted by ascending dates) ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Also: do you know up front what the interval will be? By that I mean: in this case, the interval should be 1 day, is this always the case? Where are you getting these dates from, perhaps you can ensure you only get valid data, instead of having to check in your PHP code

Comment: Data come from a user text input. I get the array of dates using `preg_match_all()` on the user input. But I wanted to make sure the user or my regular expression did not miss any date as the input should not be discontinued. Cheers.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be easier to have the user put in 1 date, then select how many subsequent dates he wants to put in? then you could do `$start = new DateTime($userInputDate);` and then loop `while($inputSubsequentDays--) {`, creating a new date on each iteration, adding it onto an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = array('2014-10-01','2014-10-01','2014-10-02','2014-10-03','2014-10-05');
$continued = true;
foreach ($dates as $key => $date) {
    if (!empty($dates[$key+1])) {
        $cDate = new DateTime($date);
        $next  = new DateTime($dates[$key+1]);
        $interval = $next->diff($cDate);
        if ($interval->d > 1) {
           $continued = false;
        }
    }
}
```

`$continued = false` then discontinuity present.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth looking into the `DateTime` class, and its goodies. In particular `DateTime::diff`, which returns a `DateInterval` instance. This enables you to safely subtract 2 dates, and determine what the time difference between those dates actually is. cf [the manual](http://www.php.net/DateTime).
In short, I've put together a little function that can be used to determine oddities in an array of date strings:

```
$dates = array('2014-10-01','2014-10-01','2014-10-02','2014-10-03','2014-10-05');
$obj = array();
foreach ($dates as $date)
{//create an array of DateTime instances from the $dates values
  $obj[] = new DateTime($date);
}
/**
 * @param array $dates (an array of DateTime instances)
 * @param string $intervalProperty = 'd' (valid valus are y, m, d, h, i, s)
 * @param int $interval = null (the value $intervalProperty should have)
 * @return array of null|DateInterval
 */
function getOddDiffs(array $dates, $intervalProperty = 'd', $interval = null)
{
    $diffs = array();
    for($i=0, $j=count($dates)-1;$i<$j;++$i)
    {//iterate $dates
        $diff = $dates[$i]->diff($dates[$i+1]);//compute diff
        if ($interval === null && $diff->{$intervalProperty})
            $interval = $diff->{$intervalProperty};//set $interval if needed/possible
        if ($diff->{$intervalProperty} !== $interval)
        {//if interval value !== $interval (type+value check required in case $interval is null)
            $diffs[] = $diff;//return the diff
        }
        else
        {
            $diffs[] = null;//null means ok
        }
    }
    return $diffs;//return results
}
```

If you want to see it in action:

## [Demo here](https://eval.in/191693)

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I chose the one from @sgt as it is in my opinion simpler and does just what I needed, even though your solution is probably more complete and versatile.

Comment: @Fredovsky: You're welcome. However: thank-you comments are discouraged on stackoverflow. You are requested _not_ to post them, but instead vote for the answers that helped. You can only accept 1 answer, but you can vote for as many as you want (PS: [this is where the thank-you comments being discouraged is explained](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasDiscontinuities($dates)
{
    // remove duplicates
    $dates = array_unique($dates);

    // get the last day
    $parts = explode('-', end($dates));
    $lastDay = (int) $parts[2];

    // if the amount of dates is smaller than the last day, there must be discontinuities
    if (count($dates) < $lastDay) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Edit regarding Elias Van Ootegem's comment, duplicates now are threated as discontinuities:

```
function hasDiscontinuities($dates)
{
    // duplicates count as discontinuities
    if ($dates != array_unique($dates)) {
        return true;
    }

    // get the last day
    $parts = explode('-', end($dates));
    $lastDay = (int) $parts[2];

    // if the amount of dates is smaller than the last day, there must be discontinuities
    if (count($dates) < $lastDay) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Second edit because of the added details in the comments:

```
function hasDiscontinuities($dates)
{
    // duplicates count as discontinuities
    if ($dates != array_unique($dates)) {
        return true;
    }

    $firstDate = new DateTime($dates[0]);
    $lastDate = new DateTime(end($dates));

    // if the difference in days is not the same as the amount of elements in the array, there are discontinuities
    if (count($dates) != $lastDate->diff($firstDate)->days + 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The duplicates should be treated as discontinuities, too IMO. Just make sure that the return value allows the caller to determine if any found mismatch was an interval of 0, and let them handle it

Comment: Thanks, but not sure this would work with an array covering several months (eg. ending the 2nd of November in this example) or not starting on the 1st of the month. (Sorry these details were not in the description).

Comment: @Fredovsky: Which is no problem for my suggested solution, that's why I suggested to use `DateTime` from the start. It can handle any valid date string.